# Sum types in C++

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions, variant, strong-typedef

At work, I ran into a situation where the best type to describe the result returned from a function would be `std::variant<uint64_t, uint64_t>` - of course, this isn't valid C++, because you can't have two variants of the same type. I could represent this as a `std::pair<bool, uint64_t>`, or where the first element of the pair is an enum, but this is a special case; a `std::variant<uint64_t, uint64_t, bool>` isn't so neatly representable, and my functional programming background really made me want `Either` - so I went to try to implement it, using the Visitor pattern as I have been able to do in other languages without native support for sum types:

```cpp
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
class EitherVisitor {
    virtual C onLeft(const A& left) = 0;
    virtual C onRight(const B& right) = 0;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
class Either {
    template <typename C>
    virtual C Accept(EitherVisitor<A, B, C> visitor) = 0;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
class Left: Either<A, B> {
private:
    A value;
public:
    Left(const A& valueIn): value(valueIn) {}

    template <typename C>
    virtual C Accept(EitherVisitor<A, B, C> visitor) {
        return visitor.onLeft(value);
    }
};

template <typename A, typename B>
class Right: Either<A, B> {
private:
    B value;
public:
    Right(const B& valueIn): value(valueIn) {}
    
    template <typename C>
    virtual C Accept(EitherVisitor<A, B, C> visitor) {
        return visitor.onRight(value);
    }
};
```

C++ rejects this, because the template method `Accept` cannot be virtual. Is there a workaround to this limitation, that would allow me to correctly represent the fundamental sum type in terms of its f-algebra and catamorphism?

Comment: `std::variant<uint64_t, uint64_t>` is perfectly cromulent, and valid, C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the problem with this approach is that ```std::visit``` doesn't work properly, so you're stuck with ```std::variant::index```. A better solution is to wrap each type in a transparent envelope class thus enabling visitation and enforcing result / error distinction by means of the type system.

Comment: I would love (for satisfying my own curiosity) to know a scenario where a `std::variant<T, T>` is better suited than "just" `T` as a return type. The "success" and the "error" scenarios return the same types that have overlapping values? Probably better to make a small wrapper class around `T`

Comment: @AndyG It is basically an enum (saying which type is active) plus a type; but sometimes you have an enum, 2 similar types, and a 3rd different type.  When you try to reduce the monad to the contents, code that works on the monad cases blows up, because the map is not the territory.  Trying to glue things so that it smartly swaps between monads and instances results in a mess.  (I'm not a functional programmer, I am just a hobbiest at it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest solution is a lightweight wrapper around `T` for `Right` and `Left`?
Basically a strong type alias (could also use Boost's [strong typedef](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp))

```
template<class T>
struct Left
{
    T val;
};

template<class T>
struct Right
{
    T val;
};
```

And then we can distinguish between them for visitation:

```
template<class T, class U>
using Either = std::variant<Left<T>, Right<U>>;

Either<int, int> TrySomething()
{
    if (rand() % 2 == 0) // get off my case about rand(), I know it's bad
        return Left<int>{0};
    else
        return Right<int>{0};
}

struct visitor
{
    template<class T>
    void operator()(const Left<T>& val_wrapper)
    {
        std::cout << "Success! Value is: " << val_wrapper.val << std::endl;
    }
    
    template<class T>
    void operator()(const Right<T>& val_wrapper)
    {
        std::cout << "Failure! Value is: " << val_wrapper.val << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    visitor v;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        auto res = TrySomething();
        std::visit(v, res);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ciWGEypfHMsi4G2b)

Answer (score 3):

`std::variant<X,X>` is valid C++.

It is a bit awkward to use, because `std::visit` doesn't give you the index, and `std::get<X>` won't work either.

The way you can work around this is to create a variant-of-indexes, which is like a strong enum.

```
template<std::size_t i>
using index_t = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, i>;

template<std::size_t i>
constexpr index_t<i> index = {};

template<std::size_t...Is>
using number = std::variant< index_t<Is>... >;

namespace helpers {
  template<class X>
  struct number_helper;
  template<std::size_t...Is>
  struct number_helper<std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
    using type=number<Is...>;
  };
}
template<std::size_t N>
using alternative = typename helpers::number_helper<std::make_index_sequence<N>>::type;
```

we can then extract the alternative from a variant:

```
namespace helpers {
  template<class...Ts, std::size_t...Is, class R=alternative<sizeof...(Ts)>>
  constexpr R get_alternative( std::variant<Ts...> const& v, std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
    constexpr R retvals[] = {
      R(index<Is>)...
    };
    return retvals[v.index()];
  }
}
template<class...Ts>
constexpr alternative<sizeof...(Ts)> get_alternative( std::variant<Ts...> const& v )
{
  return helpers::get_alternative(v, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
}
```

so now you have a `std::variant<int, int>`, you can

```
auto which = get_alternative( var );
```

and `which` is a variant, represented at runtime by an integer which is the index of the active type in `var`.  You can:

```
std::variant<int, int> var( std::in_place_index_t<1>{}, 7 );

auto which = get_alternative( var );

std::visit( [&var](auto I) {
  std::cout << std::get<I>(var) << "\n";
}, get_alternative(var) );
```

and get access to which of the alternative possibilities in `var` is active with a compile time constant.

The `get_alternative(variant)`, I find, makes `variant<X,X,X>` much more usable, and fills in the hole I think you might be running into.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/M5xnKb).

Now if you don't need a compile-time index of which one is active, you can just call `var.index()`, and visit via `visit( lambda, var )`.

When you construct the variant, you do need the compile time index to do a `variant<int, int> var( std::in_place_index_t<0>{}, 7 )`.  The wording is a *bit* awkward, because while C++ supports variants of multiples of the same type, it considers them a bit less likely than a "standard" disjoint variant outside of generic code.

But I've used this `alternative` and `get_alternative` like code to support functional programming like data glue code before.